# How do I find the equation of the circumcircle?

Tags: circles, tangent-line

Tangents are drawn from the point P(1,8) to the circle $x^2+y^2-6x-4y-11=0$ touch the circle at points A and B.So what will be the equation of the circumcircle of $\Delta$ PAB?I am not asking you to to solve the question and tell me the answer.Just tell me how to do it please.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you know where the center of the circle is and what it's radius is?? Any idea how to find where the tangent lines touch the circle?

Comment: The centre is (3,2) and radius is 2$\sqrt 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Equation of chord is given by $T = 0$:

$$x +8y-3(x+1)-2(y+8)-11=0$$

Solving it with circle equation gives points $A$ and $B$.

Now consider the equation of required circle be:

$$x^2++y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

This equation satisfies $A$, $B$, $P$, so you can find $g,f$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

General approach:

Step 1: Find the coordinates of the points $A$ and $B$.

Step 2: Find the equation of the circle through $P$, $A$, $B$.

---

For step 1, letting $M$ be the center of the circle, note that $PAMB$ is a square. (Why?) Since you know the coordinates of $P$ and $M$, you can figure out the coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

For step 2, use the general equation of a circle $x^2 + 2Px + y^2 + 2Qy + C = 0$ and plug in the coordinates for $P$, $A$ and $B$. You will get a system of linear equations and will be able to solve for $P$, $Q$ and $C$.